# Is it possible to create/start Azure VM from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, virtual-machine

Is it possible to start Azure VM from Visual Studio 2015 using Server Explorer or Cloud Explorer? Not that I can see. The reason I ask is that coming from Amazon AWS Explorer (part of AWS toolkit for Visual Studio) this could be done easily. But in Azure, unless I miss something, all you can do is see VM status and some properties and for anything else you are redirected to web portal.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible according to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8067767a-288f-4ad6-9ef2-cc0f3014988e/can-vm-be-started-from-visual-studio-2015?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be incorrect. See this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8067767a-288f-4ad6-9ef2-cc0f3014988e/can-vm-be-started-from-visual-studio-2015?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows